# Cordova plugin restore failure

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

Recently, restoration of Cordova plugins for my app has started failing despite no changes on my end. I specify my versions absolutely in both `config.xml` and `package.json` with no caret or other modifiers to allow alternate versions other than my specified version to be installed. I have no idea what caused this to suddenly break, and I don't understand the error occurring. Here's a snip of a relevant sample of errors, starting with the `config.xml` specified plugin that kicks things off:

```
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-code-push" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "cordova-plugin-code-push@1.10.1"
Running command: npm install cordova-plugin-code-push@1.10.1 --production --no-save
Command finished with error code 0: npm install,cordova-plugin-code-push@1.10.1,--production,--no-save
Copying plugin "/Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-code-push" => "/Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-code-push"
Calling plugman.install on plugin "/Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-code-push" for platform "ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-code-push" for ios
Running command: /Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
Command finished with error code 0: /Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
Dependencies detected, iterating through them...
Requesting plugin "code-push@2.0.4".
Plugin dependency "code-push" not fetched, retrieving then installing.
Running command: npm install code-push@2.0.4 --production --no-save
Command finished with error code 0: npm install,code-push@2.0.4,--production,--no-save
Copying plugin "/Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/node_modules/code-push" => "/Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/plugins/code-push"
Installing "code-push" for ios
Finding scripts for "before_plugin_install" hook from plugin code-push on ios platform only.
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_install".
Install start for "code-push" on ios.
Beginning processing of action stack for ios project...
Action stack processing complete.
Install complete for code-push on ios.
Finding scripts for "after_plugin_install" hook from plugin code-push on ios platform only.
No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_install".
Requesting plugin "cordova-plugin-file@>=4.3.0".
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file" not fetched, retrieving then installing.
Running command: npm install cordova-plugin-file@>=4.3.0 --production --no-save
Command finished with error code 0: npm install,cordova-plugin-file@>=4.3.0,--production,--no-save
Copying plugin "/Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-file" => "/Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-file"
Installing "cordova-plugin-file" for ios
Finding scripts for "before_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-file on ios platform only.
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_install".
Install start for "cordova-plugin-file" on ios.
Beginning processing of action stack for ios project...
Action stack processing complete.
Install complete for cordova-plugin-file on ios.
Finding scripts for "after_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-file on ios platform only.
No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_install".
Requesting plugin "cordova-plugin-file-transfer@>=1.3.0".
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" not fetched, retrieving then installing.
Running command: npm install cordova-plugin-file-transfer@>=1.3.0 --production --no-save
Command finished with error code 0: npm install,cordova-plugin-file-transfer@>=1.3.0,--production,--no-save
Copying plugin "/Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-file" => "/Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-file"
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-code-push': Error: Expected plugin to have ID "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" but got "cordova-plugin-file".
    at checkID (/Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:215:15)
    at /Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:199:9
    at _fulfilled (/Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/Users/distiller/BallStreetApp/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-code-push" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error: Expected plugin to have ID "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" but got "cordova-plugin-file".
```

I'm not sure how it gets confused and starts trying to look for one package when it clearly was attempting to install another.

This is on Cordova 7.1, but I also tried upgrading to Cordova 8 briefly to see if it resolved the issue. (It did not.)

I tagged the question for Ionic. I am not using Ionic, but because the same errors would presumably occur if I was doing the restore through the Ionic toolset as well since it is a thin wrapper over Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been fixed in v1.11.11 of cordova-plugin-code-push (see [PR #411](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push/pull/411)).  Note if you have NPM v5.x or higher you might need to delete or manually update the record for cordova-plugin-code-push in the package-lock.json file as well.